# What's the best way to remove all .svn directories throughout a directory hierarchy on Mac OS X?

Tags: svn, macos

Is there a command that would be useful?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the root of the working copy folder, do

```
svn export --force .
```

Answer (score 57):

```
find . -name .svn  -type d -print0 |xargs -0 rm -rf
```

Comment: Add -type d just to be sure you don't remove files named .svn?

Comment: Ok, fair enough, I've added the -type d.

Answer (score 12):

Just do an **export** from the subversion repository.

Comment: this is not what he asked for.

Answer (score 6):

For systems that support it:

```
find . -name .svn -delete
```

or, if they don't support the -delete switch:

```
find . -name .svn -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Answer (score 4):

Open Terminal window.
Go to your project folder and drag folder into Terminal window.
Now you can find your folder's path.
Run below command

```
find . -type d -name .svn -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

all .svn folder will be remove and you can upload freshcode to svn again.

Answer (score -1):

Type following command inside your folder.

```
find . -name .svn  -type d -print0 |xargs -0 rm -rf
```